# Oscillations in a Discrete Dynamical System.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

If you are familiar with SingingBanana on youtube, he posted the following question:

> There is a 10 digit number where the first digit tells me how many 0 there are in the number, the second digit tells me how many 1 there are in the number, and so on.  What is this number?

I formulated the problem as a discrete dynamical system.

Let $\mathbf{x^0}\in \mathbb{R}^{10}$ be an initial condition such that $0\leq\mathbf{x}_i\leq9$ for all $i$ between 0 and 9.

Then, the next iteration will produce

$$ \mathbf{x^{n+1}} = f(\mathbf{x^n})$$

where

$$\mathbf{x^{n+1}}_i = \mbox{How many $i$ occur in $\mathbf{x^n}$}$$

Easy to compute, or so I thought.  I'm getting stuck in oscillations between 7  1 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0 and

6  3  0  0  0 0  0  1  0  0.

So, I am stuck in a two cycle and need to find the actual steady state.

I've reasoned that the answer is 621000100.  Any ideas on how to find this analytically or computationally?

Comment: Well, I got the answer you mention via the dynamical system you propose...had to try only four different seeds (the first three gave the oscillating pair you cite).  Maybe I just got lucky?

Comment: It might be the seed, yea. I perturbed the system once it settled into oscillations and then it converged.